# Django: search query does not exist error

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to compare 2 lists, one is pulled from the DB and the second one is a list which is being compared with, before updating the DB fields with the right information. Note, the following code is for brevity to get this point across - proof of concept.

```
# create a list 
db_list = []
# fetch the DB and store them in the list.
# db_list will contains: ['D01', 'D02', 'D03', 'D04', 'D05', 'D06']
for each in User.objects.all():
    db_list.append(each.username)

# new list that needs to be added to DB, also contains some overlaping data from db_list.
second_list = ['XY12','D01','VA02','HM01','D04','HM03','D126']

# just a counter to loop through
cc = 0
for each in second_list:
    # for each item on the second_list we need to check if that value 
    # already exists in the DB, if so update its value with the current time.
    # If not, pass to else and create a new record.
    if second_list.count(db_list[cc]):
        model = User.objects.get(username=each)
        model.last_seen = timezone.now()
        model.save()
    else:
        # this method of initialising might not be the correct way but this works :/
        model = User()
        gg = gg()
        model.username = each
        model.last_seen = timezone.now()

        # this is a foreignkey in the
        # users table which corresponds to GG table. many to one relationship
        model.gg = GG.objects.get(gg='IG07') 

        model.save()
    cc += 1 #increase counter and loop until list exhausts.
```

The issue is if the first item in the second_list does not match an item when comparing the db_list, it throws the error "User matching query does not exist." However if the first item from second_list contains an item that already exists from db_list, then the code executes perfectly. Even updates the entries from the second_list that are not in the DB yet. It puzzles me as to why the first element has to match when doing this kind of comparison.

tl;dr:

```
does not work when first item on second list differes
db_list['D01', 'D02', 'D03', 'D04', 'D05', 'D06']
second_list['XY12','D01','VA02','HM01','D04','HM03','D126']

does work when first item on second list matches db_list
db_list['D01', 'D02', 'D03', 'D04', 'D05', 'D06']
second_list['D01','XY12','VA02','HM01','D04','HM03','D126']
```

### Update: I figured out the fix!

in my initial code, I was fetching the data from DB and using that to compare with a new list that is being used to create new DB entries. That method was confusing and double work. Thus we now just validate if the entry exists in the DB first and update or we create a new entry. the code below is simple and it works.

```
second_list = ['XY12','D01','VA02','HM01','D04','HM03','D126'] 
    for each in second_list:
        # verify if the user exists in DB first if not create
        if User.objects.filter(username=each).exists():
            # the print is for console logging/tshoot
            print(f'{each} exists. updating..')
            model = User.objects.get(username=each)
            model.last_seen = timezone.now()
            model.save()
        else:
            # the print is for console logging/tshoot
            print(f'{each} does not exists. creating')
            model = User()
            gg = gg()
            model.username = each
            model.last_seen = timezone.now()
            model.gg = GG.objects.get(gg='IG123')
            model.save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in my initial code, I was fetching the data from DB and using that to compare with a new list that is being used to create new DB entries. That method was confusing and double work. Thus we now just validate if the entry exists in the DB first and update or we create a new entry. the code below is simple and it works.

```
second_list = ['XY12','D01','VA02','HM01','D04','HM03','D126'] 
    for each in second_list:
        # verify if the user exists in DB first if not create
        if User.objects.filter(username=each).exists():
            # the print is for console logging/tshoot
            print(f'{each} exists. updating..')
            model = User.objects.get(username=each)
            model.last_seen = timezone.now()
            model.save()
        else:
            # the print is for console logging/tshoot
            print(f'{each} does not exists. creating')
            model = User()
            gg = gg()
            model.username = each
            model.last_seen = timezone.now()
            model.gg = GG.objects.get(gg='IG123')
            model.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't at all understand what you are trying to do with `if second_list.count(db_list[cc])`, or indeed what `cc` is doing at all. If you want to check if the element is in the db_list, then just do `if each in db_list`.

However, your entire code can be massively simplified.

```
gg = GG.objects.get(gg='IG07')
for item in second_list:
    obj, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=item, defaults={'gg': gg, 'last_seen': timezone.now())
    if not created:
       item.last_seen = timezone.now()
       item.save()
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time reply, appreciate it :)  the CC was a variable used to loop through the index of the list. My initial implementation might have been vague, but it kinda worked. After your invaluable feedback, I manage to figure out the issue and make it work. I'll be updating the code above for you to check.

Answer (score 0):

You could just do a [get_or_create()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create) for each item in your second list. Your code could look something like this:

```
second_list = ['XY12','D01','VA02','HM01','D04','HM03','D126']
for each in second_list:
    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(username=each)
    if created:
        gg = gg()
        user.gg = gg
    user.last_seen = timezone.now()
    user.save()
```

the function get or create will check in your db if the user already exists or not. If not the variable created will equal to True and it will create a new user object for you with the username you used to query the db and be assigned to the first variable (user in this case). If the user already exists the object will also be assigned to the variable user, but the variable created will be False

Comment: thanks for the insight. I did look into this method, works in a way but far from my thinking. After reading up on the methods get_or_create() & update_or_create(), i figured out a way that would help my code. All I needed was to check if user exists first by calling upon 

`if User.objects.filter(username=each).exists():
            print(f'{each} exists. updating..')
            model = User.objects.get(username=each)
            model.last_seen = timezone.now()
            model.save()` 

if that is true then just update the columns for that entry else create a new entry